# How to locate a hyperlink within a webpage?

Tags: links

My friend sent me this link:

```
https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/autonomy-moral/notes.html
```

which I suspect can be found in the link

```
https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/autonomy-moral/
```

I would like to know where the first link appears in the second link?

Comment: Link `https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/autonomy-moral/notes.html` is not there. There are only relative links to `notes.html`. So if you move only `https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/autonomy-moral/`(not notes.html) somewhere else, linking will be lost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The link can be found in each footnote:

[image]

I find it by seeing the page source (<kbd>Ctrl + U</kbd>), then search for `note`.

Comment: Link `https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/autonomy-moral/notes.html` is not there. There are only relative links to `notes.html`.